# OCaml how to build statically project

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, ocaml, static-libraries, ocamlbuild

I've to prepare my OCaml project to compile/link/run on system where some libraries are not availible (yojson, curl, cryptokit but it's probably not so important) how may I do it?

So far I was using:

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs curl,yojson,netstring,cryptokit,netclient,lablgtk2.auto-init,pgocaml tweetomat.native
```

it obviously won't work if some packages are missing. My attempt was to look for libraries path typing

```
$ ocamlfind printconf path
```

and manually copy missing libraries' folders to project's folder, here is listining of them

```
$ tree -r libs

libs/
├── yojson
│   ├── yojson.o
│   ├── yojson.mli
│   ├── yojson.cmx
│   ├── yojson.cmo
│   ├── yojson.cmi
│   ├── yojson_biniou.o
│   ├── yojson_biniou.mli
│   ├── yojson_biniou.cmx
│   ├── yojson_biniou.cmo
│   ├── yojson_biniou.cmi
│   └── META
├── curl
│   ├── META
│   ├── libcurl-helper.a
│   ├── curl.mli
│   ├── curl.cmxa
│   ├── curl.cmi
│   ├── curl.cma
│   └── curl.a
└── cryptokit
    ├── META
    ├── libcryptokit_stubs.a
    ├── cryptokit.mli
    ├── cryptokit.cmxs
    ├── cryptokit.cmxa
    ├── cryptokit.cmx
    ├── cryptokit.cmi
    ├── cryptokit.cma
    └── cryptokit.a
```

Ok so I tried to compile step-by-step every single file from project and then compile everything to executable using:

```
$ ocamlc -c twitter_oauth.mli
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package netstring,netclient -I ./libs/cryptokit/ \
    -c twitter_oauth.ml
$ ocamlc -c connection.mli
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -I ./libs/curl/ -c connection.ml
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -I ./libs/yojson/ -c parser.ml
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package pgocaml -c sql.ml
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package lablgtk2.auto-init,pgocaml -c gui.ml
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package lablgtk2.auto-init,pgocaml,netstring,netclient \
    -I ./libs/cryptokit/ -I ./libs/curl/ -I ./libs/yojson/ -o tweetomat \
    yojson.cmo curl.cma cryptokit.cma \
    twitter_oauth.cmo connection.cmo parser.cmo sql.cmo gui.cmo
```

but I'm getting:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while linking ./libs/yojson/yojson.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Bi_outbuf'
```

I googled a little and it looks like yojson is not built statically and needs 'biniou' library to fullfill dependencies (I'm not sure about statically build but it looks like that). And in fact after changing last command to (changes are marked by asterisks):

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package lablgtk2.auto-init,**biniou**,pgocaml,netstring,netclient \
    -I ./libs/cryptokit/ -I ./libs/curl/ -I ./libs/yojson/ -o tweetomat \
    **biniou.cma** yojson.cmo curl.cma cryptokit.cma \
    twitter_oauth.cmo connection.cmo parser.cmo sql.cmo gui.cmo
```

previous error does not occur but I've new one:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while linking ./libs/yojson/yojson.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Easy_format'
```

oh god I won't include every single library on which yojson/curl/cryptokit depends >:(.
Can you help me guys? Moreover does there exist some simpler way to do that using ocamlbuild?

Comment: You can use "ocamlobjinfo <file>" to determine what other external libraries are required.

Comment: ... but this is the entire point of these build systems, so I don't know why you're calling all these build steps by hand. Am I to understand you want to distribute the compiled libraries for others to compile against? Why not compile your project statically for distribution? (assuming licenses allow this).

Comment: >Am I to understand you want to distribute the compiled libraries for others to compile against?
There is no exact reason why I am doing that, I want just to be able to build my project from source files *.ml, *.mli (and maybe some additional files like these libraries above) up to executable. I'd be grateful if you could elaborate "Why not compile your project statically for distribution?". Would it work on another distribution without mentioned libraries? If so it is the proof I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes it would work without external libraries. What you are doing --as i understand it-- is trying to distribute all the external libraries with your source so compiling your project on a different system without those libraries installed explicitly will succeed?

Comment: I don't believe you can do what I've described in byte-code.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly. You are saying that I cannot distribute source files etc and simulate whole compile-link process on another computer but solution using statically pre-compiled files (not the source files and additional stuff like above) will work?

Comment: You can do that, I'm not understanding why you would want to as opposed to just compiling everything statically and directly. I've mentioned how you can look up the dependencies programatically, you can also use ocamlfind to query dependences (`ocamlfind query -r -i-format <package>`. You may be confused because I'm also being tepid in saying you are within the license agreements of these packages do even do what you're stating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify include paths for dependencies manually - let `ocamlfind` handle it. So the question remains on how to make that libraries available via `ocamlfind`.

Either:

- Use `opam` to download and install missing dependencies
- If `opam` dependency is not an option - distribute other libraries as tarballs together with your project and make the build script unpack and build them when needed (build steps may be different for each library) - and install as usual (via `ocamlfind`).

  There may be a problem of `ocamlfind` installing into system directory writable by `root` only. This can be handled by setting environment variable telling another directory for `ocamlfind` to install to and lookup from.

  That would be manual bundling until we have it automatic from `opam` one day.